# how to download the ssl certificate from a website?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, wget

I want to download the ssl certificate from, say https://www.google.com, using wget or any other commands. Any unix command line? wget or openssl?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I found the answer. Openssl provides it.

> openssl s_client -connect ${REMHOST}:${REMPORT}

Comment: also `openssl x509 -text <<EOF cert-text EOF` to see details of the certificate

Comment: `sudo rm -f cert.pem && sudo echo -n | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ./cert.pem` courtesy of http://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-ssl-certificate-from-a-website

Comment: [this](http://superuser.com/a/641396/96477) accomplishes the same and skips the `sed` hack.

Comment: This just checks one certificate, what if the service is part of a load balanced group of servers, of which each have a different certificate, possibly signed by a different root CA? 
Or in other words, a mitm attack might let this request go trough to the real site, and then direct other requests to his servers. Are there any ways to check this? And to get a list of all certificates an domain really has?

Comment: @JensTimmerman _"Or in other words, a mitm attack might let this request go trough to the real site, and then direct other requests to his servers."_ That is not possible unless the man-in-the-middle has a valid certificate for the target server (or the client is silly does not check the server certificate). Evidently, if the server sometimes offers a different certificate you can only hope to probably eventually get them all by repeating connection attempts.

Comment: @pulkitsinghal why using -f for rm on a file? never do this dangerous action

Answer (score 394):

In order to download the certificate, you need to use the client built into openssl like so:

```
</dev/null openssl s_client -connect $HOST:$PORTNUMBER -servername $SERVERNAME \
    | openssl x509 > /tmp/$SERVERNAME.cert
```

That will save the certificate to `/tmp/$SERVERNAME.cert`.

The `-servername` is used to select the correct certificate when multiple are presented, in the case of SNI.

You can use `-showcerts` if you want to download all the certificates in the chain. But if you just want to download the server certificate, there is no need to specify `-showcerts`.  The `x509` at the end will strip out the intermediate certs, you will need to use `sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/p'` instead of the x509 at the end.

`</dev/null` indicates that nothing should be sent to the server, so that the connection is released.

`openssl x509` removes information about the certificate chain and connection details. This is the preferred format to import the certificate into other keystores.

Comment: appreciate that you not only gave a good answer, but also a precise explanation.

Comment: Does `-showcerts` show the server/leaf cert too? I thought it only displayed intermediates when that switch was included.

Comment: As the answer said, `s_client` always shows the server cert (if there is one, i.e. the server responds to hello and doesn't choose an anonymous suite). `-showcerts` shows *all* the certs received, server cert first then intermediates and/or root.

Comment: what a great answer.

Comment: this doesn't work in the presences of a proxy, though.

Comment: This also doesn't work with servers that use SNI (multiple certificates/domains on a single IP-adress). To avoid problems, specify openssl's servername parameter: openssl s_client -connect HOST:PORTNUMBER -servername CN

Comment: A shorter alternative to the `sed` command is `openssl x509`. Without any additional arguments, reads a PEM-formatted cert from stdin and prints it back to stdout in PEM format, ignoring anything that's not between the `-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-` and `-END CERTIFICATE-` lines.

Comment: @Thomas True but that only returns 1 certificate. If you need multiple certificates, as in the chain, you need sed. For example: `openssl s_client -connect $server:$port -servername $server -showcerts 2>&1 < /dev/null | sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/p' > chain.pem`

Comment: openssl 1.1.0 and greater does support proxies now with the `-proxy` option (e.g. `-proxy 127.0.0.1:3000`).

Comment: @NickSpacek Is there also a way to make it work with a proxy that requires authentication?

Comment: Getting `s_client: must not provide both -connect option and target parameter` error when executing this.

Answer (score 33):

The [GNUTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/) client tool, `gnutls-cli`, can also make this easy:

```sh
gnutls-cli --print-cert www.example.com \
        < /dev/null \
        > www.example.com.certs
```

The program is designed to provide an interactive client to the site, so you need to give it empty input (in this example, from `/dev/null`) to end the interactive session.

Comment: how would it make gnutls connect through (the system wide configured) https proxy and print the certificate it exchages?

Comment: this prints out too many certs, i dont know which

Comment: this gnutls-cli gives the latest cert, i got the old cert when using openssl s_client

Answer (score 24):

```
true | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509
```

this mode of  openssl expects stdin, so we provide it via `true |`, this connects to the server specified in the -connect parameter. `2>/dev/null` silences errors (optional), we can pass the whole output into the x509 parser, specifying `/dev/stdin` to use the shell pipe as the input file. And that will output just the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` portion of the `s_client` output. You can redirect that to a file by adding `> google.com.pem` to the end of the command.

---

As best I can tell, this does not verify the certificate chain, it only can tell you what ssl identity the end server provides.

Comment: (1) this doesn't really improve the answers from 6 years ago (2) `x509` reads stdin by default so `-in /dev/stdin` is redundant (3) `s_client` verifies the server cert correctly chains to a local trust anchor (root) and is unexpired, but you've suppressed the information that would show this (4) it does NOT check for revocation (5) it checks the _name_ in the server cert only in 1.0.2 and then not by default (but you can easily check that yourself by looking at the cert afterward)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, the question is how to download certificate, but not show chain information. I like the openssl x509 much better than sed in another answer.

Comment: this works neatly, tks

Comment: works but it gives me the old cert, use gnutls-cli better

Comment: @datdinhquoc are there multiple certificates being served? I speculate that one tool is returning the first x509 certificate, and another the last. `gnutls-cli` in my experience shows all certificates served, i expect openssl would do the same. When handling multiple certificates it can be tricky, if you have python, I have an example x509-loader here that could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39313870/1695680

Answer (score 11):

based on @bignose answer, here is a self-contained version that fits well in e.g. a chef recipe:

```
sudo apt-get install gnutls-bin 
gnutls-cli --print-cert myserver.com </dev/null| sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > myserver.crt
sudo cp myserver.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myserver.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative syntax using Ex and process substitution:

```
ex +'/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/p' <(echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443) -scq > file.crt
```